# How to copy from couple folders back in the hierarchy into the current folder?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, copy

I just came to an interesting question in Linux. I want to find a shortcut for copying from multiple folder back in the path to the current path. For example:

A/B/C/D/E> cp ../../../example.txt .

I want to see if there is any shortcut for the above command, instead of typing (..) multiple times.

Thanks

Comment: Start from top level: `/home/...` or whatever?

Comment: I was wondering maybe we can also define an alias for this.
For example, I have created an alias for cd ../../.. (..3). I thought maybe I can create something similar to it for this.

Comment: You could always create a symlink:  ln -s ../../.. B; cp B/example.txt .